# Selenium unresponsive after waiting for page to load

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, wait

**Background:**

I am using Python to download a page's source code. I have Selenium sign in to the website and then "find" the HTML.

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("account_id")
elem.send_keys("username")
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("password")
elem.send_keys("abc123")
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

print "Finding element..."
html = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*')
```

The HTML is then saved to a text file, and this works flawlessly, usually finishing after 5 seconds.

**The problem:**

If I try to wait for the page's (rather complex) JavaScript to load first, Selenium can't find the element. I have tried the following:

```
import time
...
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

print "Waiting for page to load..."
time.sleep(10)

print "Finding element..."
html = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*')
```

which after the last print, never finishes.  The similar method

```
wait = raw_input("Press Enter after the page has finished loading.")
```

has the same problem of never finding anything.

I have also tried this less "brute-force" method:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import selenium.webdriver.support.ui as ui
...
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

print "Waiting for page to load..."
element = ui.WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "SomeElement")))
```

which never stops waiting, regardless of what element ID I use.

I am new to Selenium and not sure what else to try.

Comment: if the element is in an iframe you have to switch to iframe. not sure if it is but it worths having a look

Comment: Turns out it is in an iframe, but I end up in pretty much the same situation. I can get the HTML of the iframe before the JavaScript loads using switch_to_frame("name"), but if I do the same after the JavaScript has loaded, it won't find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't really a solution, but a workaround that eliminated the problem for me was switching from using a Chrome driver to the Firefox one.

ETA: Chrome driver does not work on Linux.